# How can I contribute to "Launch click-to-deploy software" in Google compute cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I see some offerings in that section of compute cloud. We have been actively creating PostgreSQL failover instances for last couple of years. How can we contribute those to Google compute cloud so that other users can help from it?

Comment: Have you tried https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/ ?  You'll need to sign up at https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1zQa29jRJTDX_1A3_L7QHdeh6sRd8Z21HIqLSLb7RCrk/viewform for whitelisting and ideally allow "our team to contact you" (it's an opt-in) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet is to contact someone in the [sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) . Another way is to subscribe to [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com) (ex. gce-discussion) and add any information or contribution you deem to be noteworthy for the community.